# network eth and network Ropsten

Tags: ropsten

in the network of the ether , i sent eth 2.62 but on the network ropsten eth 
 of0xe2fcd50EfdD674C26f894aB5ad71fEcB14b7cDA4 = Ropsten wallet. money did not come, but they can be seen in the same wallet, but on the network of the ether, i can go into the wallet / but  can not send it back, an error is written in the network. how to send money? Can I send money after Constantinople?

Comment: It seems your transaction was in Ethereum mainnet https://etherscan.io/address/0xe2fcd50EfdD674C26f894aB5ad71fEcB14b7cDA4. Ropsten is a testnet and uses a different coin from mainnet. Most exchanges only work with mainnet. In some wallet you need to explicitely switch between mainnet and testnet. If you need some ether for Ropsten search for a Ropsten faucet.

Comment: So the network does not support the usual efir. So I lost them? I understand correctly? if they run Constantinople money does not appear?

Comment: If you have the private key that generates that address then you should be able to access funds with a wallet that have access to mainnet for example MyCrypto or MyEtherWallet. Constantinople is a hard fork but you should have access to your funds without problem after it is applied.

Comment: oooh/ thank you / Thank you for your help Ismael. respect Yuri